# How do I get a group count with multiple columns in the group with a virtual attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Keeping is simple assume I have a model "Loan" that has 2 attributes "Type" and "Status".  Type as possible values of "Home", "Auto", "Building" and Status has possible values of "Open", "Pending", "Closed" and nil.

Without manually writing the SQL (using group and count?) how do I get the results of:

`select type, status, count(*) from loans group by 1, 2;`

I could do

`Load.group(:type, :status).count()`

But there are situations where status might be nil.  In that case I want to replace the nil with "Unknown"

I tried adding a virtual attribute to the model:

```
def usable_status
  status.nil? ? 'Unknown' : status
end
```

So I could then do
`Load.group(:type, :usable_status).count()`

But count didn't seem to recognize the virtual attribute since it is trying to pass it directly to the database.

Ideas?

Comment: ActiveRecord will convert any chained ActiveRecord methods to an SQL query. The method will have no effect on the query. I would suggest converting 'Unknown' into nil instead when passing it into the query instead. Much easier to achieve

Comment: Alternatively make status a non nullable column with the default  "Unknown".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's pretty easy to achieve by combining the rails styling with the SQL functionality:

```
Loan.group(:type, "COALESCE(status, 'Unknown')").count()
```

Comment: I went with this suggestion.  Still would like to avoid embedding SQL in my code, that should be what an ORM is for.  But this gets the job done.